# Bound for zeros of complex polynomial-like function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let us define for all $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\} $ 
$$P_n(z)= 1+\frac{1}{z}+ \frac{1}{2!z^2}+\frac{1}{3!z^3}+ ...+\frac{1}{n!z^n}$$.
Prove that $\forall {\epsilon>0}$ there exists $N$ such that $\forall n>N$ the following holds $$P_n(z)=0 \implies |z|<\epsilon$$

I would appreciate any hints or solutions to this problem.

Comment: The function $f(z)=e^{1/z}$ is never zero and $P_n\to f$ uniformly on $K_\epsilon=\{z:\ |z|\geq \epsilon\}$. Apply the argument principle to $f$ on the circle $|z|=\epsilon$ (clockwise). Conclude that the value of the integral in the theorem for $f$ is the same as that for $P_n$ for $n$ large enough. Conclude from the argument principle for $P_n$ that it has no zeros in $K_\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is not true. Then there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for each $N$ there exist $k_N >N$ and a point $z_{k_N}$ with $p_{k_N}(z_{k_N}) =0$ and $|z_{k_N}| \geq \epsilon$. Since $\frac 1 {z_{k_N}} $ is bounded it has  a convergent subsequence. Let $z$ be the limit of such a subsequence. By taking limit in $p_{k_N}(z_{k_N}) =0$ conclude that $\sum \frac {z^{n}} {n!}=0$ which means $e^{z}=0$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Could you clarify how to take the limits in order to get the contradiction?